# How to use enum in constant class in Dart for decorator?

Tags: dart, enums, constants, decorator

Example with the decorator:

```dart
enum Ids {
  apple,
}


class TestDecorator {
  const TestDecorator({required final this.typeId});
  final int typeId;
}

@TestDecorator(typeId: Ids.apple.index) // this line will throw an error
class Apple{
...
}
```

It shows an error - `Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions. Try making the argument a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the constructor`

The first question is why the enum index is not constant?
And the second question - is there is a way to solve this mystery?

Thanks for help!

Comment: `.index` calls a getter, and there's no way in Dart to indicate that a function call can be evaluated at compile-time.  Can you use `Ids` instead of an `int`?

Comment: @jamesdlin no, unfortunately, cannot:( The more concrete example is a [hive field decorators](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/blob/master/hive/lib/src/annotations/hive_field.dart) which have int as a field..